# WPF Canvas items and DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

Is there a way that I can use non-UIElements in a canvas if I have a DataTemplate (or something similar) for them?  I feel like I have done this before, and that it is possible, but I can't figure it out.  Here is some code...

```
<Window x:Class="EntityTranslator.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EntityTranslator"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

  <Window.Resources>
    <local:Entity x:Key="DesignEntity}" EntityName="Test" />

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Entity}">
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
    <Canvas>
      <local:Entity EntityName="Test" />
    </Canvas>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: have your tried it ? 
i see no reason why this shouldn't work

Comment: @eranotzer of course I tried it, this is the code that complains that 'local:Entity' is not a UIElement and that is what canvas expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that you cant add model items to a Panel, just UI elements. For to do this that you want, you need to do some like this:

```
   <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfApplication2:Entity}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding EntityName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Your resources, and:

```
        <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding SomeEntityCollection}>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
```

Try this, and also you may set the X and Y properties from the model, setting the ItemsContainerStyle. Hope this works for you...

Comment: This is perfect!  I can get down to business and don't have to mess with wrapping everything in a content presenter.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap them in a [ContentPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx) or [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx), which are controls that can host any object type in their `Content`

```
<ContentPresenter>
    <local:Entity EntityName="Test" />
</ContentPresenter>
```

The `ContentPresenter` will draw the item using your implicit `DataTemplate` automatically